# How to make nginx return 404 on empty files?

Tags: nginx

I am looking to see if it is possible to do a conditional rewrite based on the file size. Something like:

```
if (!-s $request_filename) {
    return 404;
}
```

I'm assuming -s returns true if the file exists and is non-empty. I need this because i have a script that dynamically creates files and those files should not be served until i have finished writing to them. Hence they should 404 if the file is empty.

Comment: That's bad idea. What will you do if file is partially written?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid this issue by making the script write to a temporary file, and after writing has finished, rename the file to the final filename.

Comment: yes, i understand that it is one possibility. unfortunately, the script is complex and i don't have full control over how it works.